# Apache Camel + Spring Boot + IBM MQ

Tags: spring, apache-camel, websphere, ibm-mq

I want to use Apache Camel to get a message on IBM MQ in a spring boot project.
I use sprin boot annotation based.
I dont find any fully example: pom.xml, receiver, configuration class, ...

Is there anyone to help me? Any link, documentation, ...?

Thanks a lot of

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [a new Spring Boot Starter for MQ](http://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring) that may help here. The README shows how to modify the JMS Getting Started sample [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/) to use IBM MQ instead of ActiveMQ. And the MQ jars - including this starter - are all on Maven Central for easy access.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I used IBM MQ before but 
I want to integrate IBM MQ  and CAMEL in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for an example that uses Spring Boot, Camel and ActiveMQ to get a first impression. Since you use Camel most differences between IBM MQ and ActiveMQ should be hidden.

However, you have to use the standard [JMS component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jms/src/main/docs/jms-component.adoc) instead of the dedicated [ActiveMQ component](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) of Camel.

Answer (score 0):

In your Application class, you will need create a bean for a IBM component, I just did it for an application in spring xml, like this:

```
<bean id="cf" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="transportType" value="1" />
    <property name="hostName" value="localhost" />
    <property name="port" value="1414" />
    <property name="queueManager" value="QMGRSCORE" />
    <property name="channel" value="EXTAPP.SRVCONN" />
</bean>
```

But once I did a bean connection for a MongDB in spring boot, may you can do something like this:

```
@Bean(name = "myDb")
public MongoClient myDb() {
    return new MongoClient();
}
```

But putting the IBM values inside this bean.